# WordPress Media Library Folders + Custom Linux Server Hosting

Tags: plugins, rest-api, media

I'm coming to you because I have a big problem with my hosting and the functioning of the FileBird - WordPress Media Library Folders plugin. I created my hosting on a NAS, on a virtual machine with Apache.

This plugin doesn't work and after several tests, it's obviously due to my custom hosting. On other standard sites with public hosting, I have no problem with this plugin.

I think FileBird - WordPress Media Library Folders (folder creation, storage, sorting) can't access the REST API (according to their guide). I need this plugin necessarily, I can't do without it, because I deal with more than 16,000 photos on this site, and I want it to be sorted by folder and by theme, etc.

I tried similar plugins, they have the same problem, they load endlessly and do not work.

Can you help me? Do you have an idea?

Thanks a lot,

Julien

Comment: I'm not sure how we would be able to help you. You should contact the plugin support and try to get them to help you figure this out. If that doesn't work / meanwhile you can already try other plugins. Or get in contact with your hosting provider and clear up why the software doesn't work in this setup but in others.

Comment: Hello,
I have contacted them, see if they answer me.
I have little hope, unfortunately.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out ! Thanks to the wonderful FileBird's team !

There is the answer :

Add to your function.php file this line of code :

```
if (defined('NJFB_REST_URL')) {
    add_filter('filebird_json_url', function(){
        return site_url("index.php/wp-json/" . NJFB_REST_URL);
    });
```

Thank me later ! ;)